# Does Linq search the entire database when I run a select statement with a time restricting where clauses?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, linq

Say I'm running a linq query to select all customers in a table where some column `DateOfCreation` (`datetime`) is within the last 30 days, and there are years worth of customers in the table.

Does the query continue searching every single row after it's gone beyond 30 days into the past? For this example assume there is an auto-incrementing integer primary key - maybe `CustomerID`, and the rows have been inserted at time of creation, so they are also sorted by `DateOfCreation`.

Comment: If the `DateOfCreation` field is indexed, no, it wont. If it isn't it probably will.

Comment: It will depend on whether or not your DateOfCreation is indexed or not. If not, a full table scan will be required which will read every row.

Comment: Okay, thank you both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a linq query which will search for all data in the last 30 days that matches the test value, like this:

```
var result = dataContext.MyTable.Where(r => r.Value == testValue &&
                                       r => r.DateOfCreation > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30));
```

This translates to the following SQL:

```
select * from MyTable
where Value = testValue
and DateOfCreation > DATEADD(day,-30,GetDate())
```

so the query will have to search every row of the table to find the right data, but such a query (if the table is indexed correctly with an index on `DateOfCreation`) will be relatively quick. If the column has an index it will mean that SQL will not have to scan the entire table to find the rows that satisfy the query.

If you are experiencing problems use something like LINQPad to convert your linq to SQL then you can run that directly on the database and use the SQL tools (Execution planes, SQL Profiler) to find where the bottlenecks are. The solution may be adding indexes etc. to the tables or ultimately rewrite the query.

Comment: The index makes it quick because it doesn't require it to scan the entire table (you don't really make that clear)

Comment: Another option besides LINQPad to view the SQL query that gets produced is to put a break-point immediately after you populate result (but before you enumerate with ToList() or whatever). Then you can examine the value of result and it should give you the SQL.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ queries don't really have anything to do with this question.  When you do a LINQ query such as:

```
from e in db.Entities 
where DateOfCreation > startDateRange 
    && DateOfCreation < endDateRange
```

LINQ translates it into a query similar to:

```
select 'Column1', 'Column2', '...ColumnN' from Entities
where DateOfCreation > 'startDateRangeValue'
    and DateOfCreation < 'endDateRangeValue'
```

As mentioned in the comments, if you have an index on the `DateOfCreation` field, then it won't need to do a full table scan (Read every row).